# Difference between hook_form_alter and hook_field_attach_form

Tags: forms

I was attempting to add default values to the addressfield field type (on the Drupal Commerce billing pane), and originally tried doing this in hook_form_alter and it did not work. I then found the module commerce_extra_address_populate which used hook_field_attach_form, and it worked.

When would you use hook_form_alter and when hook_field_attach_form when trying to modify a form, and why didn't hook_form_alter work in my scenario?

I populated an array of fields

```
$fields = array(
  "name_block" => array(
    "rank" => $rank->name,
    "first_name" => $user_fields->field_first_name['und'][0]['value'],
    "middle_name" => $user_fields->field_mcaf_middle_initial['und'][0]['value'],
    "last_name" => $user_fields->field_last_name['und'][0]['value'],
    "suffix" => $suffix->name,
    "credentials"=> $credentials->name,
  ),
  "organisation_block" => array(
    "organisation_name" = >$user_fields->field_mcaf_profile_organization['und'][0]['value'],
  ),
);
```

and then looped through it to set the form values

```
foreach($fields as $gkey => $group) {
  foreach ($group as $fkey => $value) {
    //dpm($fkey." - ".$value);
    if (!isset($form['commerce_customer_address'][$langcode][0]['#address'][$fkey])) {
      //dpm("hete");
      $form['commerce_customer_address'][$langcode][0]['#address'][$fkey] = $value;
      //$element[$gkey][$fkey]['#default_value'] = $value;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: without seeing what code you tried I don't know how one could answer why it didn't work.

Comment: Read Help Center, topics about asking. It is not generally allowed to ask for code without providing code you already tried.

Comment: "add default values to the addressfield field type" Since addressfields are implemented as ctools plugins, you should probably be looking at a plugin. It might be much better than manipulating the existing forms.